# Use columns from the main query in the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, field

Is there any way to get a column in real time, from a main query, and use it in a subquery?

Something like this: (Use A.item in the subquery)

```
SELECT item1, * 
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN 
(
    select * 
    from TableB B 
    where A.item = B.item
) on A.x = B.x;
```

I need to modify this existing query. It worked before, but now that the database changed, I need to do some modifications, add some comparisons. As you can see there are a lot of JOINS, and one of them is a subquery. I need to add a comparison from a column from the main query (from the table T0 for example) to the subquery (like this: `T6.UnionAll_Empresa = T0.UnionALl_Empresa`)

```
Select T0.UnionAll_Empresa,<STUFF>

from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OINV T0 with (nolock)
inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..INV6 T1 with (nolock) on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry and t0.UnionAll_Empresa = t1.UnionAll_Empresa
inner join

(
select 
t1.CompanyID,
T2.CompanyDb,
t1.OurNumber,
T6.BankCode,
T6.BankName,
T3.[Description] Situation,
T1.[Status],
T5.Descrption nomeStatus,
T1.Origin,
T1.DocEntry,
T1.DocType,
T1.ControlKey,
T1.CardCode,
T4.[Description] ContractBank,
T1.PayMethodCode,
T1.DueDate,
T1.DocDate,
T1.InstallmentID,
T1.InstallmentValue,
T1.Correction,
T1.InterestContractural,
T1.FineContract,
T1.ValueAbatment,
T1.ValueDiscount,
T1.ValueFineLate,
T1.ValueInterestDaysOfLate,
T1.OtherIncreases,
T1.ValueInWords,
T1.ValueDocument,
T1.DigitalLine,
T1.Document
from [IntegrationBank]..BillOfExchange T1 with (nolock)
    inner join [InterCompany2]..CompanyHierarchy T2 with (nolock) on T1.CompanyID = T2.ID
    left join [IntegrationBank]..BillOfExchangeSituation T3 with (nolock) on T1.Situation = T3.ID 
    inner join [IntegrationBank]..ContractBank T4 with (nolock) on T1.ContractBank = T4.ID 
    inner join [IntegrationBank]..BoeStatus T5 with (nolock) on T1.[Status] = T5.ID 
    inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..ODSC T6 with (nolock) on T4.BankKey = T6.AbsEntry and **T6.UnionAll_Empresa = T0.UnionALl_Empresa** --I need to do this 
where T1.[Status] <> 5 
and T2.CompanyDb = **T0.UnionAll_Empresa** --I need to do this
) TBI on (T1.DocEntry = TBI.DocEntry and T1.InstlmntID = TBI.InstallmentID and TBI.DocType = T1.ObjType )
inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OCTG T2 on T0.GroupNum = T2.GroupNum and T0.UnionAll_Empresa = T2.UnionAll_Empresa
inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OSLP T3 on T0.SlpCode = T3.SlpCode and T0.UnionAll_Empresa = T3.UnionAll_Empresa
where not exists (select 1
        from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..RIN1 A with (nolock) 
                inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..ORIN B with (nolock) on A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry and A.UnionAll_Empresa = B.UnionAll_Empresa
        where A.BaseEntry = T0.DocEntry
        and   B.SeqCode = ''1'' )
```

Comment: can you specify what you mean by "get a field in real time"? Real time? What does that mean?

Comment: You cannot do this because this is not a subquery. This is derived table. Depending on your database you might be able to do that. MS Sql Server has `cross apply / outer apply` for this purposes.

More importantly, why do you need it? Why is join not suitable?

Comment: I updated my answer for your actual code.  You can just add another condition to your `JOIN` and be done.

Answer (score 45):

You can user OUTER APPLY

```
   SELECT  *
    FROM    tbl1
            OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                    currency_id,
                                    SUM(taxrate) AS taxrate
                          FROM      tbl2
                          WHERE     wuptr.currency_id = tbl1.currency_id
                          GROUP BY  tbl2.currencyid
                        )
```

Comment: This is actually the correct answer that works for cases where subquery approach cannot be used or is impractical.

Answer (score 20):

You don't need a subquery for that:

```
SELECT item1, * 
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN 
   TableB B 
     ON A.item = B.item
     AND A.x = B.x;
```

I can't think of a scenario where you would need to `JOIN` on a subquery with a filter like that where it wouldn't be equivalent to just reference the field directly in the outer query.

You can reference the outer table in the subquery in the `WHERE` clause, though:

```
SELECT <stuff>
FROM Table t
WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT 1 from TableB B 
               WHERE t.id = b.id)
```

**EDIT**

For your actual code, just change the `JOIN` criteria to this:

```
) TBI on (T1.DocEntry = TBI.DocEntry
          and T1.InstlmntID = TBI.InstallmentID 
          and TBI.DocType = T1.ObjType
          AND TBI.CompanyDB = T0.UnionAll_Empresa )
```

Comment: Well, this was just an example. The real query is a little complex, and I really would like an approach like the one I said, even if I had to use some sort of global variable or whatever =/

Comment: @JoãoGuilherme I assumed it was a simplification.  What exactly do you need this for?  `JOIN` conditions exist for scenarios like this.

Comment: you could try naming the sub query ie SELECT * FROM a, (SELECT * FROM WHERE a.x=y) b WHERE... You should be able to do what you want. There may be a limit to how deep you can nest if its more than 3 that could be an issue. Looking on the net could it by syntax -  on (A.x = B.x)

Comment: @Alex - you HAVE to alias it if you are `JOIN`ing a derived table like that, so I don't think that will help very much.

Comment: sadly haven't got db conn to try stuff but seems to be stuff you want here: http://www.akadia.com/services/sqlsrv_subqueries.html

Comment: @Alex Did you even read the question?  He knows how to write a derived table, he wants an outer query reference in a derived table which isn't doable in SS.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to join on to a subquery and "get a column in real-time"/ reference a column from the main query, then there is a trick to doing this.

You can't access the tables which are outside of the subquery if it's used as an aliased table, in other words, this SQL can never access A:

```
...
INNER JOIN 
(
    select * 
    from TableB B 
    where A.item = B.item
) on A.x = B.x;
```

The way to access A would be like this:

```
SELECT item1, * 
FROM TableA A 
INNER JOIN TableB on TableB.item = TableA.item and TableB.item in
(
    select top 1 B.Item
    from TableB B 
    where A.item = B.item
)
```

Just ignore the "top 1" piece, I just added that to show that there may a reason for doing a join like this.
So, basically if you want to reference an item from the query in the subquery, just move the subquery to the ON section of a join and use the IN keyword as illustrated above.

Comment: That's super costly query.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this by naming the tables of the main query and the nested query.
For example:

```
SELECT continent, name, population FROM world x
  WHERE population >= ALL
    (SELECT population FROM world y
        WHERE y.continent=x.continent
          AND population>0)
```

reference: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial

Comment: Reference on the `ALL` keyword https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why people are over-complicating this. @JNK is correct that you can move the predicate into the main query. For completeness, I will demonstrate.

You have two predicates in your subquery that reference `T0`:

```
T6.UnionAll_Empresa = T0.UnionAll_Empresa
T2.CompanyDb = T0.UnionAll_Empresa
```

The first is an `INNER JOIN` predicate on the table `T6`, and the second a `WHERE` clause - these are both "hard" filters, and will filter out results that don't match (unlike a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which will simply set reference to that table's values to `NULL`).

Well, since `T6.UnionAll_Empresa` and `T2.CompanyDb` both need to filter against `T0.UnionAll_Empresa`, then we can simply change the `INNER JOIN` predicate on `T6` to this:

```
T2.CompanyDb = T6.UnionAll_Empresa
```

Then, we can remove the `WHERE` clause in the subquery, and we can add this `JOIN` predicate to `TBI` in the main query:

```
TBI.CompanyDb = T0.UnionAll_Empresa
```

...making the entire query this:

```
Select T0.UnionAll_Empresa,<STUFF>

from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OINV T0 with (nolock)
inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..INV6 T1 with (nolock) on t0.DocEntry = t1.DocEntry and t0.UnionAll_Empresa = t1.UnionAll_Empresa
inner join
(
    select 
    t1.CompanyID,
    T2.CompanyDb,
    t1.OurNumber,
    T6.BankCode,
    T6.BankName,
    T3.[Description] Situation,
    T1.[Status],
    T5.Descrption nomeStatus,
    T1.Origin,
    T1.DocEntry,
    T1.DocType,
    T1.ControlKey,
    T1.CardCode,
    T4.[Description] ContractBank,
    T1.PayMethodCode,
    T1.DueDate,
    T1.DocDate,
    T1.InstallmentID,
    T1.InstallmentValue,
    T1.Correction,
    T1.InterestContractural,
    T1.FineContract,
    T1.ValueAbatment,
    T1.ValueDiscount,
    T1.ValueFineLate,
    T1.ValueInterestDaysOfLate,
    T1.OtherIncreases,
    T1.ValueInWords,
    T1.ValueDocument,
    T1.DigitalLine,
    T1.Document
    from [IntegrationBank]..BillOfExchange T1 with (nolock)
    inner join [InterCompany2]..CompanyHierarchy T2 with (nolock) on T1.CompanyID = T2.ID
    left join [IntegrationBank]..BillOfExchangeSituation T3 with (nolock) on T1.Situation = T3.ID 
    inner join [IntegrationBank]..ContractBank T4 with (nolock) on T1.ContractBank = T4.ID 
    inner join [IntegrationBank]..BoeStatus T5 with (nolock) on T1.[Status] = T5.ID 
    inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..ODSC T6 with (nolock) on T4.BankKey = T6.AbsEntry and T2.CompanyDb = T6.UnionAll_Empresa
    where T1.[Status] <> 5 
) TBI on (T1.DocEntry = TBI.DocEntry and T1.InstlmntID = TBI.InstallmentID and TBI.DocType = T1.ObjType and TBI.CompanyDb = T0.UnionAll_Empresa)
inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OCTG T2 on T0.GroupNum = T2.GroupNum and T0.UnionAll_Empresa = T2.UnionAll_Empresa
inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..OSLP T3 on T0.SlpCode = T3.SlpCode and T0.UnionAll_Empresa = T3.UnionAll_Empresa
where not exists (
    select 1
    from [UNION_ALL_BASES]..RIN1 A with (nolock) 
    inner join [UNION_ALL_BASES]..ORIN B with (nolock) on A.DocEntry = B.DocEntry and A.UnionAll_Empresa = B.UnionAll_Empresa
    where A.BaseEntry = T0.DocEntry
    and B.SeqCode = ''1''
)
```

This is entirely equivalent to what you have, and removes any reference to `T0` from your subquery.